# C# programming-code for sum of digits and reverse number

Tags: c#

I wrote a code to find the sum of the digits and the reverse of a number-

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int number, sum = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number:");
        number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        while (number!= 0)
        {
            int m = number % 10;
            number = number / 10;
            sum = sum + m;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Sum of digits of the number:" + sum);
        Console.ReadLine();

        int reverse = 0;

        while (number!= 0)
        {
            reverse = reverse * 10;
            reverse = reverse + number % 10;
            number = number / 10;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Reversed Number is:" + reverse);
        Console.ReadLine();



    }
```

but, the output for reversed number comes as 0. I checked my code, and I am not sure what is wrong with it.

Comment: Step through your code [in the debugger](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and look what happens to `number`.

Comment: you're `while` statements appear to be better suited as `for` statements, since you're setting an initial value, modifying it in the loop, and exiting the loop when it's value meets a condition. For example: `for (var number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); number > 0; number /= 10) { sum += number % 10; }` Not that it matters here, it just caught my eye.

Answer (score 3):

You modify `number` as you sum the digits so when you try to go through the second loop, `number` is already at 0. Save off the input and reset `number` before the second loop:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter a number:");
int input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
number = input;

while (number!= 0)
{
    // ...
}
Console.WriteLine("Sum of digits of the number:" + sum);

number = input; // reset number back to original input

// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

There's also a possible solution to the problem using LINQ:

```
        int number = 1234567890;

        int sumOfDigits = number.ToString().Select(c => int.Parse(c.ToString())).Sum();
        int reversedNumber = int.Parse(new string(number.ToString().Reverse().ToArray()));

        Console.WriteLine($"sum of digits: {sumOfDigits}");
        Console.WriteLine($"reversed number: {reversedNumber}");
```